# Returning a value from a method and using it in another class - Java

Tags: java

Currently in my `Maze` class I have two methods

```
public Set<Integer> getNode(int node) {
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(adjList.get(node));
}
```

and

```
public int getNumberOfNodes() {
        return adjList.size();
    }
```

I am trying to pull through my current node into my `DFS` class but I seem to be missing something. Currently with my `DFS` class I have this.

```
private int[] route;
private boolean[] visited;


public DFS(Maze maze, int input) {
        int startNode = 0;
        int goalNode = 1;
        route = new int[maze.getadjList(node)]; << errors here
        visited = new boolean[maze.adjList.getNode()]; << errors here
        //Takes user's input and runs desired function
        if(input == 1){
        findOne(maze, startNode, goalNode);
        }
        else if (input == 2){
        findAll(maze, startNode, goalNode);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("input invalid. No Solution Returned");
        }
    }
```

Feel free to ask me anything if I can help. Thanks

---

Full `Maze` class if needed:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Maze {

    final Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> adjList = new HashMap<>();
    /**
     * The main constructor that takes a String for reading maze file.
     *
     * @param file
     */
    public Maze(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(file)) {
            while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                int node1 = scan.nextInt();
                int node2 = scan.nextInt();
                this.connect(node1, node2);
                this.connect(node2, node1);
            }
        }
    }



    /**
     * Makes a unidirectional connection from node1 to node2.
     */
    private void connect(int node1, int node2) {
        if (!this.adjList.containsKey(node1)) {
            this.adjList.put(node1, new HashSet<Integer>());
        }
        this.adjList.get(node1).add(node2);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a human-readable description of the adjacency lists.
     */
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Set<Integer>> adj : this.adjList.entrySet()) {
            int from = adj.getKey();
            Set<Integer> to = adj.getValue();
            s.append(from).append(" connected to ").append(to).append('\n');
        }
        return s.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the set of nodes connected to a particular node.
     *
     * @param node - the node whose neighbors should be fetched
     */
    public Iterable<Integer> getadjList(int node) {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(adjList.get(node));
    }

    public Set<Integer> getNode(int node) {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(adjList.get(node));
    }

    public int getNumberOfNodes() {
        return adjList.size();
    }

    /**
     * Demonstration of file reading.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.err.print("Enter File: ");
        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(System.in);
        String file = scanFile.nextLine();
        Maze m = new Maze(new File(file));
        System.out.println(m);

    }

}
```

Comment: I've read this three times and I still can't tell what you need or what's going wrong.

Comment: Ill post the full code for the maze and DFS below if that would help?

Comment: I don't need more code, I need more details about where you're running into trouble.

Comment: What are you trying to do in `route = new int[maze.getadjList(node)];` and  `visited = new boolean[maze.adjList.getNode()];`?

Comment: I need to pass the node value from my `Maze` class to my `DFS` class so that it can be used when I traverse through my inputted data

Comment: thats where I am trying to get my current node value to be passed to thats just some attempts at trying to get it to work

Comment: You cannot convert an `Iterable` into an array type like that. Your intentions are still quite unclear.

Comment: Essentially my maze outputs at the minute all the values from a .txt file and there corresponding nodes they are connected to. I am now trying to perform a depth first search. But to traverse my graph created by the `maze` class I need to get the value's from some of my methods.

Comment: If that doesn't help I don't really know how else to explain it sorry :(

Comment: In DFS, shouldn't you first instantiate the arrays route = new int[maze.getNumberOfNodes()] and visited = new boolean[ maze.getNumberOfNodes()].

Comment: Thanks Ian I think your write with that, I'll try it as soon as I get back and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Ian your a life saver, worked a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

These statements look like they are trying to create a new `int` array and a new `boolean` array:

```
route = new int[maze.getadjList(node)]; << errors here
visited = new boolean[maze.adjList.getNode()]; << errors here
```

but to create an array the parameter between the square brackets must be an `int`.
Its value gives the size of the array.

The functions you are calling do not return `int`s, hence you get errors.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ian Mc stated in the comments the problem was resolved by first initiating the arrays using.

```
route = new int[maze.getNumberOfNodes()]
visited = new boolean[ maze.getNumberOfNodes()]
```